# Input inside Arrays (java)?

Tags: java, arrays, input

So, I have a very messy code. The purpose of the code is to find the minimum and maximum values of a set of numbers that the user entered using arrays. The problem is I don't know how to put the Array elements (Elements) into my array (numbersArray).  Here's what I have so far :

```
package com.company;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner elements = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter in number of numbers:");
        String num = elements.nextLine();

        int numArrayElements = Integer.parseInt(num);
        System.out.println("Enter in numbers please: ");
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = console.nextLine();

        int Elements = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

        int [] numbersArray = new int[numArrayElements];

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < numbersArray.length ; i++) {
            int temp = numArrayElements.nextInt();
            numbersArray[i] = temp;
            sum += temp;
        }
        Arrays.sort(numbersArray);
        System.out.println((sum - numbersArray[numbersArray.length-1]) 
            + " " + (sum - numbersArray[0]));
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that I can put Elements into numbersArray?

Comment: This code is indeed pretty horrible. Does it even compile? numArrayElements is an integer which has no method "nextInt". Apart from that, if you question is just how to put something into an array, then you are already doing that: array[index] = n will put the value n into the array "array" at index "index".

Comment: If your question is how to parse a String containing a list of integers into an array of said integers, try String.split and Integer.parseInt and then add these to the loop in an array

Comment: Note Java naming conventions, it should be `int elements` and not `int Elements`. Variable names always lower-case, methods too. Only class names are upper-case.

Comment: For example if the input is supposed to be comma separated (which you need to tell the user and verify) just use input.split(",") and the array resulting from that can be looped and each value be parsed as an int.

Comment: The code does not compile. For example the method `nextInt` is not defined on `numArrayElements` since this is of type `int` and not `Scanner`. It would help if you give an example of what you want to achieve. As far as I understood you want to memorize some user entered values and then find the max and min value.

Comment: [OT, but hopefully interesting] Suppose the user inputs one number at a time and that each time your program has to output what the min and max are *so far* and ask for a new number. Could you exploit knowing a partial solution (the min and max you just output) when the new number is input? Can you exploit this for a leaner memory footprint for your program?

Answer (score 0):

Your major problem is the part where you try to read values entered by the user:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < numbersArray.length ; i++) {
    int temp = numArrayElements.nextInt();
    ...
}
```

The variable `numArrayElements` is of type `int`, you can't call a method `nextInt` on it, it does not exist.

The method, however, exists for objects of type `Scanner`, like your `elements` variable.

After that your code probably compiles and does something useful. At least you set the array items correctly by using

```
numbersArray[i] = temp;
```

I'm not that sure about the min/max part though. I don't get why you need the `sum` if you sort the array. After sorting you can just take the first (*min*) and last element (*max*) given by `numbersArray[0]` and `numbersArray[numbersArray.length - 1]`.

And I'm not sure why you do the parsing stuff in between, does not seem necessary. Same holds for the second scanner, not needed since you already have one.

---

Let me show you a cleaner approach.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

// Amount of values
System.out.println("Enter amount of values:");
int amount = scanner.nextInt();

// Read values
System.out.println("Enter " + amount + " values:");
int[] values = new int[amount];
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    values[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}

// Compute max and min
...
```

For the last part you have several options. The most efficient would probably be to remember it already at the moment where you read the values. Your sorting approach works too, but is much more work than needed since you don't need the order of all elements, you only need the min and max element.

Let's first do a manual approach

```
// Compute max and min
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for (int value : values) {
    if (value > max) {
        max = value;
    }
    if (value < min) {
        min = value;
    }
}
```

The second approach uses a built-in method which essentially does the same. However, it is less efficient since we will first need to built a `Collection` on top of the array and then do two iterations instead of only one (one for max, one for min). Also, due to the conversion we need wrapper objects `Integer` instead of primitive values `int`.

```
// Compute max and min
Collection<Integer> valuesAsColl = Arrays.asList(values);
int max = Collections.max(valuesAsColl);
int min = Collections.min(valuesAsColl);
```

The third approach uses the Java Stream API (since Java 8), looks elegant and does not need to convert stuff to `Integer` or `Collection`. But the two iterations instead of one remain.

```
// Compute max and min
int max = Arrays.stream(values).max();
int min = Arrays.stream(values).min();
```

Answer (score 0):

I not understand your ask .. however this code for set array size from user and numbers of array by user..

```
public class JavaApplication2 {

 public static int[] numbers() {
 Scanner element = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("please insert array long : ");
  int count = element.nextInt();
  System.out.print("enter numers : ");
    element.nextLine(); // throw away the newline.
       int [] numbers = new int[count];
  Scanner numScanner = new Scanner(element.nextLine());
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (numScanner.hasNextInt()) {
                numbers[i] = numScanner.nextInt();
            } else {
                System.out.println("You didn't provide enough numbers");
                break;
            }
        }
    return numbers;
 }
  public static void main(String[] args) {

   int[] numbersa = numbers();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbersa));
  }
}
```